# How can I get the same result in JPA hibernate as querying "select * from table where ..."?

Tags: java, hibernate

I'm new to ORM interface, and I'm trying to connect to my databases with Hibernate.

What I've figured out so far is:

- With a serializable object, I can get a persistent object with
  `Person p = session.get(Person.class, serializable);`
- I can get all the objects by a list with
  `List people = session.createQuery("FROM Person").list();`

What I need is to find a row that meets a certain condition, such as `SELECT * FROM person WHERE name="Kim" AND age=30;`

However, the above two aren't the ways to achieve this.

```java
@Entity
@Table(name = "person")
public class Person {
  @Id
  private Integer id;  // I can use this variable when using session.get(Person.class, serializable) , but I cannot know the id of my target row.
  private String name;
  private Integer age;
...
```

Should I iterate all the objects in `people`, and check whether all the member variables match what I want?

Is there any simple way to achieve this?

Comment: You should be using the standard JPA interfaces rather than Hibernate's internal `Session`, and you're looking for JPQL (or Spring Data, if that's an option for you).

Comment: You could use the JPA criteria API: [Using the Criteria API to Create Queries](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/gjitv.html) or the Hibernate criteria Api: https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.2/api/org/hibernate/Criteria.html

Answer (score 0):

First and most importantly, never put user input in a query like this

```
SELECT * FROM person WHERE name="Kim" AND age=30;
```

You have to use Prepared Statements. Learn why from [Bobby Tables](https://bobby-tables.com/).

Secondly, you should use the JPA interface `EntityManager` instead of Hibernate's `Session` as the second one anchors you to a specific implementation, rather than the wider standard.

With the EntityManager you get an object by id like this:

```
Person p = em.find(Person.class, id);
```

To get a list of People you can create a JPQL query like this:

```
TypedQuery<Person> query = em.createQuery("SELECT p FROM Person p WHERE p.name = :name AND p.age = :age", Person.class);
query.setParameter("name", "Kim"); // :param1 defines a parameter named "param1" in the query
query.setParameter("age", 30);
List<Person> results = query.getResultList();
```

You could also do this in one chain if you don't need to reuse the query with different parameters on a loop.

```
List<Person> results = em.createQuery(..., Person.class)
        .setParameter("name", "Kim")
        .setParameter("age", 30)
        .getResultList();
```

The reason to put every call on a new row is in case an exception occurs it will give you the proper row to look for. If they're all in one row, then that's not very useful.

If your query is a SELECT, and it needs to return exactly one result every time, you can use `getSingleResult()` instead of `getResultList()`. If you do that and the query did return more than one result, it will throw a `NonUniqueResultException`. If the query did not return any results it will throw a `NoResultException` instead of returning null.

If your query is NOT a SELECT, then you have to use `executeUpdate()` to invoke it after setting the parameters.

There are many resources to get you started, but generally if its for a Hibernate version before 5.2 you should consider it outdated, and it will likely be more difficult.